# Xamarin forms Picker on android change Ok and Cancel text

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

So I have a challenge similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46227028/xamarin-forms-picker-on-android-change-cancel-text), to change the OK and Cancel button texts on Android and have been reading about [Android resources](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_1_-_android_resource_basics/), therefore decided I shall have my \Resources\values\Strings.xml edited in my Android project and containing two dedicated ok/cancel key-values.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <string name="library_name">My App</string>
   <string name="ok">Fine</string>
   <string name="cancel">Nope</string>
</resources>

File build action for my XML is set to AndroidResource, although this does not impact the Picker ok/cancel button texts. What have I missed? It has to be working according to docs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have update my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this does not impact the Picker ok/cancel button texts.

**Your Application string resources:**

- **Resource.String.** --> Resources\values\Strings.xml

---

**System string resources:**

- **Android.Resource.String.**

For more `Android.Resource` information, you could read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631278/useful-android-system-resources).

You could find it in [Source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/PickerRenderer.cs#L124) that it use the android string resource :

```
builder.SetNegativeButton(global::Android.Resource.String.Cancel, (s, a) => ...
builder.SetPositiveButton(global::Android.Resource.String.Ok, (s, a) => ...
```

So you cant change the `Ok` and `Cancel` text. As mister_giga said, if you still want change the text, you have to reinvent whole bicycle.

**Update :**

I have write a custom `PickerRenderer` to implement your feature, and I have post my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46227028/xamarin-forms-picker-on-android-change-cancel-text/47151948#47151948)  . Hope this can help you.

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC7ZC.png).

Comment: @DawidIreno, if this can help you, could you please mark it as an answer?